# How to make overlaid contour plots with python?

Tags: python, contour

Using Python, how to create two(or more) color contour plots, each with their own color map, but overlaid into a single image with the same x and y axes?

Comment: Try http://matplotlib.org/examples/

Answer (score 0):

You can save each layer into a PNG file with a transparent background and overlay them in Photoshop, Gimp or ImageMagick.